# Pattern for removing an unknown/dynamic number of subviews from collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

My application has a collectionView with collectionViewCells that take up the entire screen. Each collectionViewCell has a background view and multiple "annotations" (views) on it. I am creating these annotation views dynamically in a method on the collectionViewCell subclass, because each cell has a potentially different number of annotations.

In the collectionViewCell subclasses, I am doing

```
[self.contentView addSubview:annotationView];
```

for each of the annotation views.

My problem is that the annotations are not being removed from the cell when it is dequeued and prepared to be reused, so I end up with annotations for multiple cells shown incorrectly.

I know that I could do something like

```
[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Is this the best way to remove the dynamically created subviews, or is there a better one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have other views in your cell than dynamic ones, you need some better way to access them than `cell.contentView.subviews`. I would suggest creating custom `UICollectionViewCell` and creating methods for manipulation of dynamic subviews:

```
@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

- (void) addDynamicSubview:(UIView*)view;
- (void) removeAllDynamicSubviews;

@end

@implementation CustomCell {
    NSMutableArray* dynamicSubviews;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    dynamicSubviews = [NSMutableArray new];
}

- (void) addDynamicSubview:(UIView*)view {
    [dynamicSubviews addObject:view];
    [self.contentView addSubview:view];
}

- (void) removeAllDynamicSubviews {
    [dynamicSubviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [dynamicSubviews removeAllObjects];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a good approach. I implemented -prepareForReuse in this class, and called -removeAllDynamicSubviews there.